# Get view variables in layout script in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm just starting out in Zend Framework 3 after using 1.12 for years. When I pass a variable to the view model it shows up just fine in the view script. However, I'm having trouble accessing those variables inside my layout scripts.

The following code doesn't work

```
<?= $this->vars('title');  ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found out how to do this in a controller:

```
$this->layout()->setVariable('title', 'SUPPORT CENTER');
```

Comment: how do you echo the var in the layout?

Comment: echo $this->title;